# Если во время установки grub я примонтировал раздел с виндовс нарушает ли это какие-то условия использования?

Tags: linux, установка, grub

Grub не находил раздел с виндовс, поэтому пришлось ручками монтировать sdaX к папке /mnt/windows7,os-prober и grub нашли раздел. Не нарушает ли это политику использования Виндовс?

Comment: Нет.           Не нарушает.

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto А если я удаляю отдельные элементы gnome? (Например игры, ненужный хлам), нарушает ли это условия использования?

Comment: Если ты из под линукса грохнешь `/mnt/windows7/Windows/System32`, то тогда это нарушит политику использования Windows. Вернее её работоспособность. Всё остальное - нет.